# Is there a way to hold a particular element of a recyclerview on the top?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, grid-layout, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

I am using a recyclerView, with a GridLayoutManager layout.

The recycler view contains 2 types on ViewHolders, one having span size equal to 3 in order to separate different types of grid elements and one of size equal to one.

What i want is to be able to hold always on the top one of the view holders of the size 3 (depending on the  horizontal scroll position), like shown in the image below.

Does anyone has any idea how to do it? If it is possible i would want to avoid to create a custom layout, is there an easier way to do it?

[grid layout exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LgZ2.png)

Comment: correct me if i am wrong. You want the grid should look like the second gridList as in image you posted.

Comment: Yes, in the second gridList image the "movies" view holder is sticked to the top until it is not change with "games" view holder" when scrolled down.

Comment: can you post your adapter code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this github project 
[StickyHeaders](https://github.com/ShamylZakariya/StickyHeaders)

You can use directly this and import it as a dependency or you can look at the code and try to implement your own "sticky" header.

Comment: any other easier way?